# mysql_fetch_array и mysql_result в одном коде

Tags: php, mysql

Нужно вытащить из базы ряд значений. Но в начале нужно только первое, а дальше - весь набор. Использую следующий код

```
$photoQwerry = mysql_query("SELECT PhotoPath FROM Photos WHERE ID=$id");
//берем первое значение из массива
if($photoQwerry){
echo mysql_result($photoQwerry,0,'PhotoPath');
}   
...
//выводим весь массив
if($photoQwerry){
while($photo = mysql_fetch_array($photoQwerry)){
    echo "$photo[PhotoPath]";
}
}
```

Код упростил и убрал лишнее, но смысл в выводе картинок. Беда в том, что первый запрос "съедает" первое значение и во втором выводе выводится все данные, кроме первой строки. Как это исправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете воспользоваться функцией `mysql_data_seek()`, вызвав ее после `mysql_result()`, которая перемещает курсор в начало результирующей таблицы. Тогда `mysql_fetch_array()` начнет чтение с первой записи.

PS Следует иметь в виду, что расширение mysql устарело и исключено из PHP 7. Лучше ориентироваться на mysqli или PDO.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
$photoQwerry = mysql_query("SELECT PhotoPath FROM Photos WHERE ID=$id");

if($photoQwerry){
    $isFirstRow = true;

    while($photo = mysql_fetch_array($photoQwerry)) {
        if ($isFirstRow) {
            echo mysql_result($photoQwerry,0,'PhotoPath');
            $isFirstRow = false;
        }
        echo "$photo[PhotoPath]";
    }
}
```

PS Только отчего бы вам для первой строки не использовать данные из `mysql_fetch_array`?

Comment: Просто между первой и второй частью есть еще код. Можно конечно прописать все в конце, примерно таким способом, как вы написали, но тогда придется еще писать кусок кода на js, чтобы он добавил результат в начало страницы((

Comment: Или я что-то не понял в вашем варианте?

Comment: Тогда вам лучше использовать вариант @cheops - через `mysql_data_seek`

Comment: Просто вы видимо не пользуетесь шаблонизаторами типа smarty - по-хорошему нужно отделять операции чтения из базы и вывода страницы на базе шаблона.

Comment: Благодарю, учту)